# How to change color of the dots in D3.js to reflect data on y scale?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am starting with the d3.js and have decided to build a weather graph but the points (or nodes?) do not change color as they should i.e. not by temperature (position on y scale) but according to their position on x scale? What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2.5px;
}

.dot {
    fill: steelblue;
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="d3/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>

var tooltip = d3.select('body').append('div')
    .style('position','absolute')

var data = [
    [new Date(1961, 0, 1), 6.3],
    [new Date(2014, 0, 1), 9.4]
];

var margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var tooltip = d3.select('body').append('div')
    .style('position', 'absolute')
    .style('padding', '0 10px')

var colors = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([5, 20])
    .range(['#000000','#ffffff'])

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .domain([new Date(1960, 0, 1), new Date(2015, 0, 1)])
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([5, 10])
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("monotone")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d[0]); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d[1]); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Teplota (ºC)");

svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line);

svg.selectAll(".dot")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .style('stroke', function(d,i) {
        return colors(i);
    })
    .style('fill', function(d,i) {
        return colors(i);
    })
    .attr("class", "dot")
    .attr("cx", line.x())
    .attr("cy", line.y())
    .attr("r", 1.5)

    .on("mouseover", function(d) {       
            tooltip.html(d[1] + 'ºC')
              .style('left', (d3.event.pageX - 35) + 'px')
              .style('top',  (d3.event.pageY - 30) + 'px')
              .style('font-size', '15px')

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your dots are currently being colored by the array index of your data. Doing it this way will color your dots based on their time series (the x axis).

In order to color your circles based on temperature set the call to colors function like so. This will reference the second data point in current array iteration (the temperature).

```
svg.selectAll(".dot")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .style('stroke', function(d,i) {
        return colors(d[1]);
    })
    .style('fill', function(d,i) {
        return colors(d[1]);
    })
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks a ton!

Comment: Excellent, would you please accept the answer as correct? :)